# What's the next logical step for this Kakuro?

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

[image: Kakuro]

The puzzle is small but frustrating.

Here's what I've deduced so far:

- In the 36 row, there are two missing digits which sum to 9, these must be 1+8 so the remaining empty cells are 2,3,4
- In the 36 column, same thing but it could be 3+6 or 4+5 missing. There must be 1 and 2 somewhere but can't nail down where
- In the 18 row, the leftmost cell is 5 or 6, so the other two sum to 5 or 6, unfortunately that still leaves lots of possibilities
- In the 19 column, there are 4 cells which sum to 10 so must be 1+2+3+4

Alternatively maybe I just overlooked something really stupid.

I have verified all pen (blue) numbers are correct using the button in the app.

Source: Puzzle Page app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with the horizontal 18 sum at the bottom.

> The cell next to the 7 cannot contain a 5, because that would force the first cell to be 6 and then the final cell would make the sum exceed 18.

From that you know that in the vertical sum

> of 36, the top empty cell must be the 6, because otherwise the empty cells would add up to just 10, which is not enough to make 36.

Comment: yep, thanks! actually I just read your first sentence "Start with the horizontal 18 sum at the bottom" and after a bit more thought I managed to reach your first deduction (without revealing spoiler) and everything else followed from there :)